# How to turn on "unused imports" highlighting in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

My PyCharm doesn't mark any imports as unused.

Me (`os` is not using):

[image]

Should be (found this picture in web):

[image]

How can I enable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen this green icon in the top right corner? You can choose which problems you want to display.
Just choose "All problems".

I tried everything: reinstalled pycharm, cleaned caches, tried other projects, etc. And this is what solved it for me

[image: I missed warnings so much]

Comment: It seems this happens in version 2021 because they added this checkmark feature.

Answer (score 2):

For the next person coming across this the following might help:

- Click "File";
- Click "Invalidate Caches / Restart..."
- Click "Invalidate and Restart"

This can resolve the problem when unused imports are not shown.

Comment: This is more optimal solution than reinstalling the IDE and dropping project settings. Thank you for the reminder of that option.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that the file I had problem with was outside the project ( a single .py file opened directly with *File->Open* ). For some reason even marking global imports as unused does not work then.

Adding the file to a project solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I reset the Pycharm settings to default with the [Restore default settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-and-ide-settings.html#restore-defaults) option.

It can now detect unused imports very well.

Answer (score 1):

In PyCharm 2022.2.3, this is noinspection comment when I select "Suppress for a statement".

[image: suppress for a statement]

So if you select "Disable inspection" by mistake

[image: by-mistake]

Then turn on the option "Unresolved references".
(Settings > Inspections > Python > Unresolved references)

[image: settings]

And then you can enable again like below screenshot.

[image: enable-again]

Answer (score 0):

I just completely reinstalled PyCharm without import IDE settings and removed project settings in project folder.

Now “unused imports” highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Close already opened PyCharm and open the file directly in PyCharm. File -> Right Click -> OpenWith -> PyCharm